# Containers and divs in CSS

Tags: css, containers

Good day,
I'm not new to CSS or DIVs but have been out of touch for long enough. Trying to work out with Containers and nested DIVs but not getting much success in doing what I'm trying to do. Have already searched enough on SO and Goog but, hopefully you can help me.

Here's the representation of what I wish to achieve.

[Screenshot of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYpc.jpg)

And here is what I have done so far ..

```css
.dealsglobal {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dealsglobal h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsindia {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dealsindia h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsleft {
    margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dealsleft img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.dealsright {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dealsglobal">
<h2>Global Coupons</h2>
    <div class="dealsleft">
 <img src="thumb-heavengifts.jpg" alt="HeavenGifts.com Web Store" align="middle" />
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
    Test
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dealsindia">
<h2>Indian Coupons</h2>
    <div class="dealsleft">
    Test
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
 Test
    </div>
</div>
```

The image just wont center, no matter what I do. I believe, somewhere I have set the property to align left or something. Can anyone please point me to the correct direction? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding this css property:

```
.dealsleft {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Jeez! How did I miss that! That fixed all the problems. I kept on messing with margin auto and what not. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for any of these 2:

```
parentSelector {
  display: block; /* can also be an inline-block, with set width */
  text-align: center;
}
childSelector {
  width: 60%; /* generic. Change it */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

... or:

```
parentSelector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
childSelector {
  max-width: 60%;    /* optional. Change it. 
                      * You don't need to set width here and, 
                      * it's OK not to limit max-width, either
                      */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have yet to learn the flex method. I will study this method now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit, but you'll get idea :

Here is html :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <h2 class="inner-text">title</h2>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
    <h5 class="inner-text">description</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2 class="inner-text">title</h2>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
    <h5 class="inner-text">description</h5>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.container{
  width: 98%;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}


.right {
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.inner-text{
  text-align:center;
}

.image{
  padding: 20px;
}

.image img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Check here jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/168e2n8t/2/)

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice way of doing it. I will try that with another page I'm trying to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can center elements inside a `div` by using `text-align:center;` for all the text elements like: `h1, p, h2, a` etc. To center an `img` or a `div` inside another `div` you can use `margin: 0 auto;` the `auto` is the important part for centering the `left` and `right` margins.

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

i've updated your code snippet.

```css
.dealsglobal {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dealsglobal h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsindia {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dealsindia h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsleft {
    margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.dealsleft img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.dealsright {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dealsglobal">
<h2>Global Coupons</h2>
    <div class="dealsleft">
 <img src="thumb-heavengifts.jpg" alt="HeavenGifts.com Web Store" align="middle" />
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
    Test
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dealsindia">
<h2>Indian Coupons</h2>
    <div class="dealsleft">
    Test
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
 Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing text align center. Although I love this fix but read somewhere that align property does not go with css3 or html5 (not too sure which one was it). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andy Align property does work with HTML5 and CSS3 (i've been using it for a long time). And no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have added background colors for visualization purposes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.subcontainer-outer {
  width: 49%;
  background-color: green;
}

.subcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h3>Container</h3>
<div id="container">
  <div class="subcontainer-outer">
    <h4>Sub container 1</h4>
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer-outer">
    <h4>Sub container 2</h4>
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gerard, that's so helpful. I like your CSS more than mine. One question though. Will the layout stay intact on smaller/big resolution displays? Will the layout stay intact on mobile devices? With the layout I have right now, the content boxes do not stay inline on a mobile device. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: What should happen is that subcontainer 2 will be below subcontainer 1 when they don't fit next to each other on a mobile device.

Comment: Hello Gerard, thanks for the reply. That's exactly what I see happening when I see the layout on a mobile device. 
Is there way to get exact layout on a mobile device as we see on a desktop computer?

Comment: For the code I provided, nothing needs to be changed to make that possible. But you likely have additional CSS (media queries?) which are out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using `flex` below an example as your requirement.

```css
.dealsglobal {
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dealsglobal h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsindia h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dealsleft {
  margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.dealsleft img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.dealsright {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="dealsglobal">
  <h2>Global Coupons</h2>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="dealsleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="HeavenGifts.com Web Store" align="middle" />
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dealsglobal">
  <h2>Global Coupons</h2>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="dealsleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="HeavenGifts.com Web Store" align="middle" />
    </div>
    <div class="dealsright">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/16/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Lokesh, it was helpful!